# MySql server has gone away when run in queue

Tags: laravel, mariadb, beanstalkd, laravel-4.2

We have maradb 10.1 and beanstalkd 1.10 and laravel 4.2
We have one query that run successfully without queue. but when run it in beanstalkd not afected and we get 'MySql server has gone away' error in log file

config:

```
wait_timeout            = 120 
max_allowed_packet      = 1024M
```

Why different behavior between with and without queue

Comment: This could be due to user permissions

Comment: Why you thinks this is permission? Its run with same mysql user

Comment: Is it ran on same server?

Comment: How long do you thing that query takes to run?

Answer (score 0):

We had similar issues and either it was because the code was running in different thread, and connection being lost, or a strange garbage collection and closing of connection for long running processes.

Anyway what we implemented is 
- when a job is reserved and starts processing we reconnect the DB always
- when we detect a connection gone away, we release the job (so it will be picked up again)

In case it happens in the middle of the processing flow, you may want to reconnect to lose work done so far on that job, if the job is somehow transactional.